# Adding resources to subresource REST API

Tags: web-development, rest, api, api-design, web-api

I'm trying to build an web API that closely represents a library of books. I currently have the following routes.

- GET /api/books
- GET /api/books/:bookID
- GET /api/libraries
- POST /api/libraries

  - This route currently accepts a `books` parameter in the body (with the body represented as an object), that should be an array of bookIDs.
- GET /api/libraries/:libraryID
- DELETE /api/libraries/:libraryID

---

What I'm trying to decide is how to allow users to add/delete books to an existing library.

**Option 1:**

- POST /api/libraries/:libraryID/books/:bookID

  - No body will be accepted in this route
- DELETE /api/libraries/:libraryID/books/:bookID

**Option 2:**

- POST /api/libraries/:libraryID/books

  - Body will be an array of bookIDs represented as an array.
- DELETE /api/libraries/:libraryID/books

  - Body will be an array of bookIDs represented as an array.

**Option 3:**

Some combination of 2 & 3, OR something completely different that I haven't thought of yet.

---

What is the most common method to handle this for a REST API? In the future I might also consider `PUT /api/libraries/:libraryID`, but that would change the entire `books` array, and replace it, as opposed to just adding or deleting a specific book(s).

Comment: I would recommend removing the `/api` prefix from all of these URLs — it adds nothing and reinforces misconceptions that APIs are something different to websites.

Comment: /api./AddBookToLibrary?libraryId=x&bookId=y is impossible to misunderstand

Answer (score 1):

Heuristic: think about how you would do it with a web site.  That alone will tell you a lot about how it would be done as an API.

> In the future I might also consider PUT /api/libraries/:libraryID, but that would change the entire books array, and replace it, as opposed to just adding or deleting a specific book(s).

In REST, this it the right basic idea.  Remote authoring is done by retrieving a representation of the resource, making local edits, and then sending back to the server a request that the server change its copy to match the local copy.

If the total representation is small, then sending the entire thing with `PUT` is fine.  A valid alternative is to describe the changes in a patch document, and send that using HTTP Patch.

On the web, the remote authoring idioms aren't nearly as common as the form idioms.  Download a form that allows you to describe some action, fill in the form details, submit the form back to the target resource via `POST`.  Form submissions have been changing the web for 25 years now, so it is a valid choice.

We should prefer to use `/api/libraries/:libraryID` as the form target, because that's the key we want to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) in the local cache.  HTTP capable caches will have the correct semantics baked into them, providing that we ourselves follow the specification.

So for your case, I'd probably have a form for adding a book, perhaps at `/api/addBook?library=:libraryID`, and another form for deleting a book, perhaps at `/api/deleteBook?library=:libraryID`.  Each of these resources would provide a representation of the form, with the appropriate fields to be filled in by the client, and meta data telling the agent to submit to `/api/libraries/:libraryID`.

If you look carefully, this suggests that you might have a lot of different forms all submitting to the same resource.  That's right - all of the actions that should change the representation of `/api/libraries/:libraryID` should be implemented as forms that POST to the same identifier.  The benefit is free caching; the trade off is that we have to prepare our endpoint for many different kinds of form submissions.